# meteor wont update data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have this code:

```
Nodes = new Meteor.Collection("nodes");
[...]
Template.list.events({
  'click .toggle': function () {
      Session.set("selected_machine", this._id);
      Nodes.update(Session.get("selected_machine"), {$set: {"conf" :{"flag": true }}});
  }
});
```

I can't convince meteor to update my entry. Theres a microsecond flash
in the DOM, but the server rejects to update.

This is my data:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d8ec4f5919ffef343c9151"), "conf" : { "flag" : false }, "name" : "sepp" }

console.log(Session.get("selected_machine")); shows me the id. Insecure Package is installed. Writing by hand in the minimongo console works as expected.

Is there a Problem because I wan't to update a subarray?
What am I doing wrong? Thank you for help

Comment: Did you try to update `name` (which is shallow) instead of `conf`? It it succeeds, it's definitely a problem of updating a subarray. Otherwise you'd check that _id property for validness.

Comment: There is no minimongo console. Do you mean the mongo console ("meteor mongo") or the browser console?

Comment: @DavidWihl I meant the meteor monogo - shell.

Comment: @raina77ow shallow update didn't work either. But Problem is solved. TY anyway

Comment: what is the this._id do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your data uses the MongoDB ObjectId, it's a known issue that Meteor can't update these values (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/61).

you could run this hack in the mongo shell (meteor mongo) to fix it (credit to [antoviaque](https://github.com/antoviaque), i just edited it for your collection)

```
db.nodes.find({}).forEach(function(el){
    db.nodes.remove({_id:el._id}); 
    el._id = el._id.toString(); 
    db.nodes.insert(el); 
});
```

Meteor sees the ObjectId just as a string and because of that MongoDB doesn't find something to update.
It works client-side, because in your local collection these _id's are converted to strings.

For experimenting you should insert data via the browser console and not via the mongo shell, because then Meteor generates UUID's for you and everything is (and will be) fine.

PS: I ran into the same problem when I started on my App.

Comment: Well done! Solved my issue in 2 seconds -- I spent the whole night on this. Maybe i've overseen it - but a big fat warning in the meteor docs wouldn't be to much to ask to the meteor folks. Probably **every** new meteor user will fall exactly in the same trap. When I try to figure out a framework I always wan't to see what comes out in the database. Thank you Rouven!

Comment: `.toString()` converts it to a string literal `ObjectId(...)` in some versions of mongo. Safer to use  `_id.str`