# Couldn't update docs in meteor, found a fix, but don't know how to use it. Where do I put it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I hit a problem with updating docs with meteor mongodb. Found a fix here

[meteor wont update data in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028941/meteor-wont-update-data-in-mongodb)

The solution comes with a piece of code, commented by the creator:

> you could run this hack in the mongo shell (meteor mongo) to fix it

What does "run this hack in the mongo shell" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your app running, run `meteor mongo` or if you're using mrt, `mrt mongo`. It will open a mongo shell so you can do DB commands directly. But mongo syntax is different. It's like:

```
db.users.find(); // returns all users
db.yourCollection.remove() // remove everything from yourCollection
```